# Is it possible to use namespace without a class

Tags: php

Is it possible to use namespace without a class?

For example:

```
namespace Foo;
// rest of the procedural code and functions
```

Asking because I have notion that namespace are only used where there are classes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) without a class, like:

```
//demo.php file
namespace FooDemo;
function first() { return "First"; }
function second() { return "Second"; }
function third() { return "Third"; }

//test.php file
require_once 'demo.php';
foreach (array("first","second","third") as $funcs) {
    echo call_user_func('FooDemo\\'.$funcs);
}
```

Did you mean something like this

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. See the [`documentation`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php).

Extract:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar;
include 'file1.php';

const FOO = 2;
function foo() {}
class foo
{
    static function staticmethod() {}
}

/* Unqualified name */
foo(); // resolves to function Foo\Bar\foo
foo::staticmethod(); // resolves to class Foo\Bar\foo, method staticmethod
echo FOO; // resolves to constant Foo\Bar\FOO

/* Qualified name */
subnamespace\foo(); // resolves to function Foo\Bar\subnamespace\foo
subnamespace\foo::staticmethod(); // resolves to class Foo\Bar\subnamespace\foo,
                              // method staticmethod
echo subnamespace\FOO; // resolves to constant Foo\Bar\subnamespace\FOO

/* Fully qualified name */
\Foo\Bar\foo(); // resolves to function Foo\Bar\foo
\Foo\Bar\foo::staticmethod(); // resolves to class Foo\Bar\foo, method staticmethod
echo \Foo\Bar\FOO; // resolves to constant Foo\Bar\FOO
?>
```